# PHP doesn't save to files

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi, apache2

I have Apache 2 and PHP installed on a Raspberry Pi 1 B+ (RASPBIAN STRETCH LITE
). I have a website running on it with a textbox and a PHP script that is supposed to save the contents of the textbox to a text file on the server when the user submits.
I tryed basically everything but the php script just wont save.
PHP does get the textbox-content (I tested it - it works just fine).

This is my PHP:

```
<?php
include "code/multiPage/topBar.html";
$dir = "/data/searches.txt";
if ($_REQUEST) {
    $input = $_REQUEST["search"];
    file_put_contents($dir, $input, FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

PHP is working properly aside from this problem.

The folder has read-write permissions for everyone.
I have also tryed to let PHP create its own folder with code similar to this:

```
if (!file_exists('path/to/directory')) {
    mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
}
```

PHP can't even do that.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was that the webserver didn't have permission to write to the directory. problem solved by running `sudo chown -R www-data var/www/html/data` thanks for the help! Have a nice day :D

Comment: spent an hour figuring out why uploaded file wasn't getting saved, until I found this! thanks for answering with your solution!

Answer (score 0):

First just try this separately from other code

```
<?php
```

file_put_contents("/data/searches.txt", "bla", FILE_APPEND);

```
?>
```

if it's not working try to get a last error

```
echo print_r( error_get_last (  ), true)
```

In order to make sure that you can write to the file you can always check if it's writable

```
if(is_writable($dir))
```

Also for debugging it's nice to see how much bites was written by file_put_contents

so the final code easy to debug will be like this:

```
<?php
include "code/multiPage/topBar.html";
$dir = "/data/searches.txt";
if(!is_writable($dir)){
    echo "cannot write to file";
}

if (!empty($_REQUEST["search"])) {
    $input = $_REQUEST["search"];
    $bitecount = file_put_contents($dir, $input, FILE_APPEND);
}
echo $bitecount . " bites were written to the file";
?>
```

There is a thing. If $_REQUEST["search"]="" or $_REQUEST["search"]=null the if($_REQUEST) will be TRUE anyway

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.   :D

Comment: Tryed it - Put the PHP in a different file, checked path.. It cant write to that location - 0 bytes saved. I'm not shure how to fix this.